# How to handle partial file so that it will not be pickup by SFTP schedule pick up script?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sftp

I have a requirement where

> when uploading the files to the pick-up folder, files will be uploaded
>   with a .tmp (or)._ (or) .filepart extensions and after successful
>   upload files will be renamed to the original file name.

This is required to avoid any partial pick-up of .xml files by settings on SFTP folder side.

**For eg. Upload with .xml.tmp and after successful upload, rename the files to .xml**

Any idea on how to achieve this in MVC, C#.

Comment: Basically instead of processing with the full upload, you will need to read the posted file as a stream, when you start reading it as a stream you create the .tmp file, you write the stream on the tmp, once done, in the finally block you can just rename the file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, once you receive the file stream from the post, the upload is "already" successful (most likely). Therefore, the moment you have the data from the post, you should already be good to write it. The only point I can remotely see here is that, the remote process either checks .xml files constantly so let's say if the .xml file is quite large, and let's assume (which wont be the case) it takes a while for you to write the stream to the remote destination, they do not want to check just part of the xml, they need all of it. If that is the case, something like the following should work (modify it for your needs);

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count < 1)
            {
                ViewBag.Result = "No files were provided";
                return PartialView("Error");
            }

            foreach (string F in Request.Files)
            {
                var FInfo = Request.Files[F];
                var TemporaryFileName = $"{FInfo.FileName}.tmp";

                try
                {

                    using (var FStream = new FileStream(TemporaryFileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        FInfo.InputStream.CopyTo(FStream);
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    ViewBag.Result = e.Message;
                    return PartialView("Error");
                }
                finally
                {
                    System.IO.File.Move(TemporaryFileName, $"{FInfo.FileName}");
                }

            }

            ViewBag.Result = "Files have been uploaded";

            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to do this in a separate folder entirely. And then do a move to the pickup folder.

Then renaming is not required.

```
private bool IsFileLocked()
        {
    try
                {
                    FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(FilePath);
                    fs.Close();
                    return false;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File locked: " + FileName);
                    return true;
                }
}
```

To check if the file is locked prior to attempting to send, might also work, or in conjunction.

I was talking about generating a local file first, once its completely done being written, simply use the File.Move() method, so you move the newly generated file from its "safe" folder, into the pickup folder, that the SFTP is continually looking for files in.

If it is picking up a file you are receiving, then it's just the check prior to attempting to do anything with it.

Comment: So you are suggesting to put the files in a local folder first. And then through some job/scheduler send them to SFTP folder?

Comment: First part yes, second part no. 
No reason to setup a scheduler.

If you have an async process, simply "Wait" for it to finish, then move it. 
If its a sync process, just move when done.